# Android deactivate production apk

Tags: android, apk

i am intend to deactivate the production mode apk from the play store, i did upload another apk in the alpha mode. However after i deactivate the production apk, the play store keep prompt the error and ask me to see the form error, however, there is no any error from the form to tell me what i have did wrong for it.  the picture has been attached. 
[image]

What should i do to deactivate the production mode and switch it to the alpha mode

Answer (score 1):

you cannot deactivate an APK and leave it with nothing unless you completely deactivate the application.

meaning, if you want to have an alpha distribution you must have an apk in production