# Remove app from production and keep testing

Tags: android, google-play-console

Someone from my team accidentally promoted app to production. However, we're using that app explicitly for testing purposes, and want it to be visible for internal testers only.

There are several other questions asking the same thing, but none of them has legit answer.

Accepted answer here suggests creating new app [Remove app from production and use beta testing instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988862/remove-app-from-production-and-use-beta-testing-instead)

Here it says it's not even possible [Android deactivate production apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418097/android-deactivate-production-apk)

So, my question is - is it possible to remove app from production while keeping testing channels available?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. We have similar situation right now, this saved us from lot of google search & even effort of contacting & waiting for google team support!

Answer (score 8):

I've contacted Google support and they confirm that it's currently unsupported. Here's a copy of their response:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support!
>
> Regarding your concerns, at this time our system does not support the
>   rollback functions for app which was already published to Production
>   track.
>
> As you stated previously, unpublishing options could not solve your
>   issue, and please noted that Google currently does not support the
>   deletion of apps with downloads from current users, past or inactive
>   users, or users that have downloaded apps for testing purposes.
>
> Consequently, the workaround under this circumstance is to upload a
>   new app with new package only to the Open Beta track for the testers
>   again.
>
> I absolutely understand this is a significant inconvenience.
>
> We hope this helps answer your question. Thanks for your understanding
>   and continued support.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible.

What you could try to do as a workaround is publish to prod an APK which isnt compatible with any device, e.g. maxSdkVersion=1 or minSdkVersion=Z, but it's possible that Play Console has some validations on these values. And this will not completely unpublish the app: it will still be visible in the Play Store, but it will not be installable at least.

Sorry, I know the answer is not very satisfying, but there is no way to completely remove an app from prod without also removing it from the other tracks.

Answer (score 1):

same question here, it's been 3 years now. but seems still not be possible.

but did someone managed to remove app from production and keep testing. anno q4 2022?

My solution / workaround for now is. to
Publish the app, wait for testusers to install it using the internal testing
and then Unpublish the app right after everyone did install the app.
the testusers will also get update on internal test track.

Problem still exists that no new testusers cannot be added, new users will get a deadlink when the app is unpbulished

Answer (score -5):

You can unpublish your app. and republish anytime. You can have a look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773305/how-to-republish-an-app-after-unpublishing-it)

> However, we're using that app explicitly for testing purposes, and want it to be visible for internal testers only.

For this, you can use [internal test.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Goto Console -> Select your app. -> Release management -> App release -> Internal test track -> manage.

[image]

Here you can manage your internal test. It allows you to test app in internal environment for **selected users/testers.**

[image]

- This internal test track app. will be only available for
  **users/testers** having **Opt-in URL** displayed in image.
- You can add upto 100testers for internal test track.
- We are using **Internal-test-track** after **Unpublishing** app. from
  play-store.

[image]

Comment: After re-publishing app, it would become visible on Production track too.

Comment: yes @Marius. from [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773365/2289835) , kindly go to **Store Presence -> Pricing & distribution** you will find **PUBLISH/UNPUBLISH** option. from there you can publish/unpublish app anytime you want. kindly check my updated answer.

Comment: If I unpublish app, I can't access opt-in url, because for that - app must be published. If app is published, it's visible in production.

Comment: absolutely not. app. published in **internal-test** will be visible to only users/testers having **Opt-in URL.**

Comment: It's already published in production, there's no button anywhere to unpublish it from production without also unpublishing from testing. Or to publish app to testing only, without publishing to production(after it was previously published on production)

Comment: I already told you in comment that. kindly go to **Store Presence -> Pricing & distribution** you will find **PUBLISH/UNPUBLISH** option.

Comment: In short, You need to **Unpublish** your current app from **Production track** and create new release in **Internal test track.**

Comment: I've asked Google Support, and indeed they confirm it's currently impossible. Please read the question more thoroughly next time you answer the question.