# unpublish production application on Google Play but leave internal test version

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I had published both versions: production and internal tests version.
Now I want to unpublish only production and leave internal tests version. I want it to be visible only for people from closed list.

How can I do that? When I select "unpublish" in "Pricing & distribution" it is unpublishing both.

Comment: i'm not sure but you can check in alpha testing option for select people

Comment: Have you tried everything on this page? https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: @Pratik18 it is possible, I had internal tests at the beginnings (no production) and it worked fine, then I added production, and now I want to have only internal again.

Comment: @J.A.P yes. I read it and did not find option to disable production and leave internal tests. There is only option for disable all.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53609473/remove-app-from-production-and-keep-testing/53619726#53619726